# Fixed length output in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, pentaho

i am using XSL Transformation to generate xml file from a different xml file. Till now i have successfully obtained output xml file using XSL transformation.But i wanted that each of the value in the output to have a fixed defined length.These length should be as follows:

member: The length of this value should be 50 characters long.
date: The length of this value should be 10 characters long.
type: The length of this value should be 6 characters long.
amount: The length of this value should be 10 characters including the decimal point and the two decimal digits.
remark: The length of this value should be 50 characters.

My input xml file is :

```
    <records>
   <record>
    <member>Vikram Singh</member>
    <transaction>
       <date>2015-02-09</date>
       <type>credit</type>
       <amount>300000</amount>
       <remark>successful</remark>
    </transaction>  
    <transaction>
       <date>2015-02-10</date>
       <type>debit</type>
       <amount>30000</amount>
       <remark>successful</remark>
    </transaction>  
    </record>
    <record>
    <member>Sudhanshu Singh</member>
    <transaction>
       <date>2015-01-13</date>
       <type>credit</type>
       <amount>100000</amount>
       <remark>successful</remark>
    </transaction>  
    <transaction>
       <date>2015-02-10</date>
       <type>debit</type>
       <amount>10000</amount>
       <remark>not successful</remark>
    </transaction>  
     </record>     
</records>
```

The output i have obtained is correct and should be like this but with fixed lengths.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transactions>
    <Transaction>
        <member>Vikram Singh</member> 
        <date>2015-02-09</date> 
        <type>credit</type> 
        <amount> 300000</amount> 
        <remark>successful</remark> 
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <member>Vikram Singh</member> 
        <date>2015-02-10</date> 
        <type>debit</type> 
        <amount> 30000</amount> 
        <remark>successful</remark> 
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <member>Sudhanshu Singh</member> 
        <date>2015-01-13</date> 
        <type>credit</type> 
        <amount> 100000</amount> 
        <remark>successful</remark> 
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <member>Sudhanshu Singh</member> 
        <date>2015-02-10</date> 
        <type>debit</type> 
        <amount> 10000</amount> 
        <remark>not successful</remark> 
    </Transaction>
</Transactions>
```

The xsl file i am using is :

```
 <xsl:template match = "/">
    <xsl:for-each select="transaction">
        <transaction>
                <member>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "$member"/>
                </member>
                <date>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "date"/>
                </date>
                <type>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "type"/>
                </type>
                <amount>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "amount"/>
                </amount>
                <remark>
                    <xsl:value-of select = "remark"/>
                </remark>
            </transaction>  
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Help me to make the output of fixed length.

Comment: "*The length of this value should be 50 characters long.*" That's not a sufficient requirement; you need to specify **exactly** what to do if the value is less than that: do you want to pad with spaces? From which side? Also, which XSLT processor are you using? It might support a padding function. -- P.S. This is a very strange requirement for an XML output; normally you see this when outputting a **text** file for consumption by older systems.

Comment: if the length of the output value is less than 50 then it should do right padding with spaces and it should be trimmed from the right side if length exceeds 50. i am using xsl Version: 1.0 and xsl Vendor: libxslt

Answer (score 2):

> i am using xsl Version: 1.0 and xsl Vendor: libxslt

Good, then you can use the EXSLT `str:align()` and `str:padding` functions. Here's a minimized example showing how to pad the `type` element to 6 characters.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/records">
    <transactions>
        <xsl:for-each select="record/transaction">
            <transaction>
                <!-- ... -->
                <type>
                    <xsl:value-of select="str:align(type, str:padding(6))"/>
                </type>
                <!-- ... -->
            </transaction>  
        </xsl:for-each>
    </transactions>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

> transformation is running without errors but it is failing to do
>   padding in output xml

Please run the following stylesheet (against any valid XML input) and report the results:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <results>
        <processsor>
            <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/>
        </processsor>  
        <support>
            <align>
                <xsl:value-of select="function-available('str:align')"/>
            </align>  
            <padding>
                <xsl:value-of select="function-available('str:padding')"/>
            </padding>  
        </support> 
        <spaces>
             <xsl:value-of select="str:padding(10)"/>
        </spaces>  
        <align>
             <xsl:value-of select="str:align('12345', '----------')"/>
        </align>  
        <combined>
            <under>
                 <xsl:value-of select="str:align('12345', str:padding(10))"/>
            </under>  
            <over>
                 <xsl:value-of select="str:align('1234567890123', str:padding(10))"/>
            </over>  
        </combined> 
    </results>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: the thing you mentioned isn't working for me ,transformation is running without errors but it is failing to do padding in output xml and also substr with concat() also not working for me.

Comment: @VikramSinghJadon Please run the test above and report the results.